# What is the meaning of "a thinly disguised price"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> They also provided an opportunity for the groom’s family to display
>   its affluence and glory in its prestige in the community. The
>   splendour of these occasions was a severe burden on a family’s
>   resources… An additional expense was the gifts to the bride’s family,
>   the betrothal presents, which were **a thinly disguised price** for the
>   person of the daughter-in-law and a clear indication of her total
>   subservience to her new family.

This article is about women in ancient China and their wedding ceremonies. I believe "for the person of the daughter-in-law" here is the bride. But what is the meaning of "a thinly disguised price"? Is it indicating that the gift is equal to the bride?

Source: https://www.ancient.eu/article/1136/women-in-ancient-china/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Thinly disguised** (usually hyphenated) is used to describe something that is officially/formally said to be one thing, but that most reasonable people would recognise as actually being something else.

In this specific context, the notable items are the *expensive gifts*.  They are *officially* gifts (i.e. optional items given to the bride's family, in celebration of the occasion); but the article implies that they are actually *expected* to be given, as a *payment* for the bride.

The value of the gifts is the **price** that has been paid to the bride's family, by the groom's family, in exchange for the bride's lifetime commitment of marital servitude.

The expectation that the bride's family should receive a payment is an unwritten/unspoken rule, and referring to these payments as *gifts* lends a veneer of traditional respectability to the process of *buying another human being*.

You may also see the term **thinly-veiled**, which might be a little too on-the-nose for an article about weddings.  Something that is thinly-disguised may also said to be ***something,* in all but name** (e.g. *these "gifts" are a payment, in all but name*).

A similar practice of exchanging goods or money in return for marrying into a family is referred to as a **dowry**, but that is more-specifically where a bride (or bride's family) gives money to a groom, in payment for taking on caring for the bride.

Comment: Interesting+1 That's why it ( "buying" the opposite sex ) is called **thinly disguised** price?

Comment: No, it is **thinly-disguised** because it is said to be a *gift*, but is actually a *payment* (and everyone knows it is really a payment).

Comment: It's also probably a reference to the concept of [bride price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bride_price).

Answer (score 8):

It's an awkwardly-written sentence. I would not have chosen to use "price" but rather "payment".  In this context, "price" would refer to how much the family wants the groom to "pay" for the bride, like a metaphorical "price tag" on her forehead.  "Payment" refers to the amount actually *paid* to meet that price.

The sentence is supposed to mean that these so-called "gifts" actually represent the value of the "purchase price" of the bride, although they are "disguised" to make it look like she is not actually being *sold*.

Although this idea of "bride price" is old-fashioned, someone cynical might say it still exists today in the custom of the engagement ring, calling this a "thinly-disguised bribe" (to assure the bride and her family that the groom is financially solvent).